# Core data update or create find updated

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have core data entity which contains fields such as name(unique), imageURL and image (saving image as data). Im downloading this data from web API which I have no control of (data in JSON).

I have to check every week if there were changes on API side and update my local database.
Sometimes its changing imageURL property and I have to detect that and download new image and remove old one. Any idea how to implement that (I would be glad for piece of code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought it was fairly straight forward.

You are able to download the images when you first get the item.

So now have a check something like...

if currentImageURL is different from newImageURL download the image.

**EDIT - To explain how it should work**

Assuming you've processed the JSON and now you have an `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries`...

You would do something like this...

```
//I'm assuming the object is called "Person"
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];

for (NSDictionary *personDictionary in downloadedArray) {

    // You need to find if there is already a person with that name
    NSPredicate *namePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", personDictionary[@"name"]];
    [request setPredicate:namePredicate];

    // use whichever NSManagedObjectContext is correct for your app
    NSArray *results = [self.moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    Person *person;

    if (results.count == 1) {
        // person already exists so get it.
        person = results[0];
    } else {
        // person doesn't exist, create it and set the name.
        person = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];

        person.name = personDictionary[@"name"];
    }

    // check the image URL has changed. If it has then set the new URL and make the image nil.
    if (![personDictionary[@"imageURL"] isEqualToString:person.imageURL]
        || !person.imageURL) {
        person.imageURL = personDictionary[@"imageURL"];
        person.image = nil;
    }

    // now download the image if necessary.
    // I would suggest leaving this here and then wait for the image to be accessed
    // by the UI. If the image is then nil you can start the download of it.

    // now save the context.
}
```

Comment: So I should download data to some kind of transient objects, then iterate them and compare to objects from fetchResult. If same object exist check if it has different imageUrl and if not exist just add it to MOC? This doesn't seem like elegant solution neither fastest one...

Comment: Well, you say the name attribute is unique. How do you make sure this is unique?

Comment: I know that the name is unique. That's how I'm doing it right now.

Comment: @b3ginneriOS I have updated to show how you should be processing each item. This can be optimised so that only one fetch is needed but this gives you a general idea.

Comment: @b3ginneriOS yes, it's essentially what you dismissed in the first comment. If you have some magic code that will do this for you I'd love to see it. lol